# How to print the key that has the most number of elements in its list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that will return the name of the key in a dictionary such that the key has the most number of elements in its list.

I managed to write a function that counts the number of values in the my animals list. I tried searching for a way to achieve this but

```
animals = { 'a': ['horse'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['giraffe','donkey']}

def how_many(dic):
    count = 0
    for x in animals: 
        if isinstance(animals[x], list): 
            count += len(animals[x]) 
    print(count)


def biggest(dic):
    p = []
    for i in range(len(animals)):
        x = how_many(dic[i])
        p.append(x)

#stuck here
```

the biggest(dic) function should print C.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a `key` argument to the built-in `max` function to do this easily:

```
animals = { 'a': ['horse'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['giraffe','donkey']}

print(max(animals.keys(), key=lambda k:len(animals[k])))
# prints 'c'
```